# Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object. When I delete a Button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm Making a POS project as a challenge for my self as I'm starting to learn XAML and C#.

The problem happens when I try to delete the button. I get an exception saying System.InvalidOperationException: 'Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.'

I have searched online a lot but didn't find anything helpful.

```
 private void CB_del_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Window window in Application.Current.Windows)
        {
            if (window.GetType() == typeof(MainWindow))
            {
                try
                {
                    foreach (Button btn_tst in ((window as MainWindow).SP_plates).Children)
                    {

                        if ((btn_tst as Button).Name == "btn_cheeseburger")

                            if (I_cheese == 1)
                            {
                                (window as MainWindow).SP_plates.Children.Remove((Button)sender);

                            }

                        if (I_cheese != 0)
                        {
                            I_cheese = I_cheese - 1;
                            String count = I_cheese.ToString();
                            String str;
                            str = "CheeseBurger  $7.5  : " + " " + count;
                            Char[] TrimChar = { '(', ')', ',', '.', '.' };
                            String Name = str.Trim(TrimChar);
                            String Name2 = Name.TrimEnd(TrimChar);
                            btn_tst.Content = Name2;
                        }

                    }


                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("test");
                    throw new InvalidOperationException();
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: On which line does the exception happen?

Comment: I cannot determine all I get is the error

Comment: It only gives me an exception without showing me where it occurs

Comment: So how can I solve it?

Comment: As a note, your usage of `window as MainWindow` looks odd. Instead of checking `window.GetType() == typeof(MainWindow)` make an assignment `var mainWindow = window as MainWindow`, then check if `mainWindow != null`,  and later only use `mainWindow`.

Comment: Basically what the click event does is that if the button that contains the order details has a value of quantity higher than one it decreases it but if the value is equal to one it completely removes it because there is no need to have an order item with zero quantity on it.

Comment: OK thanks for that note

Comment: That will help a lot actually.

Comment: The only way I was able to access the button and edit it was by its click event.

Comment: The deletion will modify the collection, breaking the foreach loop. I think this is the cause.

Comment: Yes. I think so too because when I used break after the delete method the error stop but this caused some bugs and I wasn't able to use the loop again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of deleting the button, you might consider to

- set its visibility to hidden
- set its enabled to false & set it's text to "Out of Stock"
- have a look at [Converters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) and set the Visibility of the Button to a Converter that converts the "Count" of Burgers to a visility value so it Autohides on Count == 0.

or smth alike.

Comment: You just saved me hours of research and frustration. I hope I asked here earlier

Comment: I will definitely take a look at the converters and binding and thank you very much for the tips.